# Giving upload access to anonymous users in a Huawei OBS bucket

Tags: cloud, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have created an OBS bucket in the Huawei cloud. I want users who do not have accounts in the Huawei cloud to upload files to the bucket. I do not see any option for granting permission for this specific action. However, I have granted permission for anonymous users to read and write to the OBS bucket but, that does not enable anonymous users to upload files to the bucket.

Is there any way to do this in the Huawei cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Just go to you console, click your bucket in your bucket list, and in Bucket ACLs tab, set Anonymous User has write Permissions, it works for me.

like this:
[image]